# ASP.Net Fill GridView with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: asp.net, gridview, entity

This is my page

```
Profiles pp;
    Tasks t;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["User"] != null)
        {

            pp = (Profiles)Session["User"];
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("PageLogin.aspx");
        }


    }

    private void data()
    {
        DBCOntext db= new DBCOntext ();

        var manager= db.Tasks.Where(p => p.Personnel == pp.Username).Select(q => q.Manager).FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

I took the data with data class. But I didn't fill gridview. How do I fill gridview? pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you data binding the gridview? You aren't using the manger variable anywhere that I can see.

```
GridView.DataSource = manager;
GridView.DataBind();
```